# Unknown Error Message: Check for javascript errors

Tags: future, apex, apex-code, developer-console

I have 2 questıons .
1)While writing code, this message appears on the developer console screen :'Unknown Error Message: Check for javascript errors. How can I solve this problem?

2. İn apex job my error msg -->'First error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0AWT000000L7pt2AC; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, PaymentTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate

caused by: System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future...'

I use only one future method..where ıs 2.nd future ı dont know...what can ı edıt or change ??

Can you help me?
​

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.